# Do I include non-academic works on my ORCID?

Tags: digital-researcher-id

A children's book I wrote is about to be published soon. Should I include it in my ORCID account?

ORCID is very clearly concerned with academic works. However, it would be nice if someone who wasn't sure if the author the children's book and the math papers were the same person could check on ORCID and get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would include a children's book on my ORCID account.

The [vision of ORCID](https://orcid.org/about/what-is-orcid/mission) *is a world where all who participate in research, scholarship, and innovation are uniquely identified and connected to their contributions across disciplines, borders, and time.*

Including math paper and children's books would span disciplines and borders.